# Error with resolv.conf and nslookup

Tags: ubuntu, bind

I put my DNS server in resolv.conf 10.0.2.5, but only the nameserver of 127.0.0.53 allows me to resolve lookups when I use `nslookup 10.0.2.5` or `nslookup 10.0.2.6`.

I read that there should be a DNS server address in resolv.conf.

```
root@ubuntuserver:/etc/bind/zones# nslookup 10.0.2.5
;; Got SERVFAIL reply from 10.0.2.5, trying next server
5.2.0.10.in-addr.arpa   name = ubuntuserver.com.
5.2.0.10.in-addr.arpa   name = adminserverkerberos.
5.2.0.10.in-addr.arpa   name = ubunturealm.
5.2.0.10.in-addr.arpa   name = serverkerberos.
5.2.0.10.in-addr.arpa   name = ubuntumailsystem.
```

resolv.conf:

```
nameserver 10.0.2.5
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search home
```

I want to get complete DNS query dependency from bind9 on my server and clients.

---

@Greg Askew Those ip are not mine, what happend?

```
root@ubuntuserver:/etc/bind/zones# nslookup ubuntuserver.com 10.0.2.5
Server:     10.0.2.5
Address:    10.0.2.5#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   ubuntuserver.com
Address: XXX.90.244.158
Name:   ubuntuserver.com
Address: XXX.89.244.183

root@ubuntuserver:/etc/bind/zones# nslookup clientnorbert.com 10.0.2.5
Server:     10.0.2.5
Address:    10.0.2.5#53

** server can't find clientnorbert.com: NXDOMAIN

root@ubuntuserver:/etc/bind/zones# nslookup clientnorbert.com 10.0.2.6
;; communications error to 10.0.2.6#53: connection refused
;; communications error to 10.0.2.6#53: connection refused
;; communications error to 10.0.2.6#53: connection refused
;; no servers could be reached
```

Comment: If you want to use 10.0.2.5 as a name server on the command line it needs to be the second parameter. `nslookup nametolookup 10.0.2.5`. That is the command you need to enter next.

Comment: @Greg Askew i tag you.